# How to lock/unlock HTML element with Jquery on certain condition?

Tags: jquery

I can better explain it with Raw script.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("Div").  //lock div here

        var condition=$("#value").val();
        if(condition==true){unlock div here}
        else{do nothing}
    });
</script>
```

Is there any jquery widget i have to include?

By saying lock/unlock I mean Enable/Disable.

Comment: what do you mean by lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("Div").attr('disabled','true');  //lock div here


        var condition=$("#value").val();
        if(condition==true)
              $("Div").attr('disabled','false');//{unlock div here}
        else{do nothing}
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Don't do** `$("#Div").attr('disabled','true');`, the main problem here is that with 1.6 (or sth around that) the comparison with `== true` is broken, if the attributes value is `disabled` (see http://jsfiddle.net/2vene/1/ (and switch the jquery-version)). You should rather go for [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/%C2%B4).

Secondly **div doesn't support `disabled`**, use some `input`. In this case your code will look like

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#controlId").attr('disabled','disabled');  //lock input control here

    var condition = $("#value").val();
    if(condition == true)
          $("#controlId").removeAttr('disabled');//{unlock input control here}
    else{do nothing}
});
</script>
```

You can check [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F).

**EDIT**

Optionally you can use `readonly` on `div` to lock / unlock mechanism. Check demo of [readonly](http://jsfiddle.net/2vene/7/).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "not to show", use  `hide()`, if you have any form elements in div and want to disable 'em all, you have to disable each of them one by one.